# Are Google Drive APIs JSON-based APIs or the older XML-based APIs?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing an iOS app that uses Google Drive. What to use with Google Drive APIs?:

code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

or

code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: the Objective-C library now supports version 2 of the Drive API

The Drive API is one of the new JSON-based APIs, however the [Objective-C library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) doesn't support it yet.

You can still use the older XML-based Documents List API with the [GData library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/), both the Documents List and the Drive API use the same resources (i.e. documents).

Comment: Version 2 of the Drive API is now available supported by the Objective-C library at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/